# rewrite rule on location in nginx

Tags: nginx, debian

When I write the location in, it works, when I use the same location as a rewrite rule, it doesnt!!! I dont understand the logic. Can someone please explain?

```
   location /v3/ {
            alias /var/www/api/v3/html/;
            echo $document_uri;
            echo $document_root;
            echo $request_filename;
            echo $request_uri;
            echo $fastcgi_script_name;
   }
```

When I do the above, I get

```
/v3/info.php
/var/www/api/v3/html/
/var/www/api/v3/html/info.php
/v3/info.php
/v3/info.php
```

But if I now change the location to use rewrite:

```
   location ~ ^/(v\d+)/ {
            alias /var/www/api/$1/html/;
            echo $document_uri;
            echo $document_root;
            echo $request_filename;
            echo $request_uri;
            echo $fastcgi_script_name;
   }
```

The paths all get screwed:

```
/v3/info.php
/var/www/api/v3/html/
/var/www/api/v3/html/
/v3/info.php
/v3/info.php
```

How come??

Answer (score 1):

You will need to match on the entire URL to do this.

For instance:

```
location ~ ^/(v\d+)/(.*) {
    alias /var/www/api/$1/html/$2;
```

Comment: wasnt exactly the answer i was looking for but it directed me to the right answer. thank you.

Comment: @Christian Would you like to share? Otherwise there's no point to this question at all.

Comment: Will do. Back in the office monday. Currently away.